# R: Import Excel-Sheet as character string values

Tags: r

I want to import an Excel sheet (XLS and / or XLSM) into R.
However, all values must be loaded as characters - a transformation must not be performed.

My biggest problem is that R automatically tries to identify a date and automatically converts this. This often leads to problems in my model that can't be easily undone - this R "read-in script" only acts as an auxiliary script. In addition, some numbers are converted to "num", although these should also be in "chr" format.

I already tried the readxl and openxlsx package but both have no further option to NOT transform the imported data.

Example:

```
daten <- readWorkbook(Path, sheet = Worksheet, colNames = T)
str(daten) 
Date:   chr [1:500] "01.02.2018" "01.03.2018"
Type:   chr [1:500] "01" "01" "02"
Option: chr [1:500] "TRUE" "FALSE"
Exp:    chr [1:500] "0.00003" "4.322324E-5"
```

Comment: Have you tried the `colClasses` argument of `read.xlsx` from the package `xlsx`

Comment: Yep I also tried that. The problem with the date column still remains, because all values in column "Date" are now converted to "42400"

Comment: Do you want the date displayed as "01.02.2016"?

Comment: Yes exactly but I can't use e.g. format(x, "%d.%m.%Y"). The date notation in the individual Excel sheets is very different. It ranges from "yyyy/mm/dd", to "mm_dd_yyyy". My example "01.02.2016" is only one notation of many. 
For this reason, when importing into R, no transformation should be made.

Comment: So you have different Excel sheets containing dates stored as dates (in Excel) with different date notations and you want to keep those notations and you don't want them to be converted into a general format (for example: "dd.mm.yyyy") for all sheets but to keep those individual representations?

Comment: @MartinGal This pretty much sums it up

Answer (score 4):

With readxl, try:

```
readxl::read_excel(path, col_types = "text")
```

Comment: Good idea! But the problem with the date column still remains, because the dates are now converted to "42400".

Comment: What exactly do you need? Dates are stored as a number in excel.

Comment: Excel stores dates as integers with epoch being Jan 1, 1900. So what are you looking for?

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez For reasons I don't understand the actual origin for `as.Date(42400, origin = "1899-12-31")`. :-)

Comment: You are right, Martin. In Excel, 1900-01-01 == 1. And, oddly, 1900-01-00 == 0.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. The problem is rather that the date notation in the individual Excel sheets are very different. It ranges from "yyyy/mm/dd", to "mm_dd_yyyy". My example "01.02.2016" is only one notation of many. For this reason, when importing into R, no transformation should be made in the first place.

Comment: Could you share with us a reproducible example? Perhaps select 3 to 4 different rows with different data inputs. My guess is that if Excel recognizes the input as a date, it will store it as an integer. If it does not recognize it as a date, it will store it as a text string. You just need to create a conditional statement in r to deal with different cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but an idea to solve your problem. I created an excel sheet "Sheet2.xlsx" like this:

| Date |
| --- |
| 01.02.2016 |
| 2018/02/01 |
| 31_12_2018 |

Using `openxlsx` and storing it as a workbook gives

```r
library(openxlsx)

workbook <- loadWorkbook("../../Sheet2.xlsx")

style <- getStyles(workbook)
#> [[1]]
#> A custom cell style. 
#> 
#>  Cell formatting: DATE 
#>  
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> A custom cell style. 
#> 
#>  Cell formatting: "yyyy\/mm\/dd" 
#>  
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> A custom cell style. 
#> 
#>  Cell formatting: "dd_Mm_Jyyyy"
```

So for example you can access the cell formatting for cell A3 with

```r
style[[2]]$numFmt$formatCode
#> [1] "yyyy\\/mm\\/dd"
```

Based on this information you probably find a solution to restore the custom date formats for a `format(as.Date())` function.